# Is there a way or hack to calculate some gridsearched preprocessing parts of a GridSearchCV only once?

Tags: python, pipeline, feature-selection, gridsearchcv

Time of GridSearchCV would greatly improve for my case if GridSearchCV could be made to remember the features selected in a subgrid. X, y are pandas DataFrame and Series. Also this is a simplified grid, in reality I tune C also, that makes this much slower than it needs to be. Unfortunately my custom feature selector is much slower than say SelectKBest with f_classif.

Suppose I tune the following parameters:

```
myGrid = {
          'featSel__k:     tuple(range(2, 12)),
          'mlAlgo__gamma': np.linspace(0.05, 0.35, 7)
}

myPipe = Pipeline([
                   ('preProc', RobustScaler()),
                   ('featSel', MyFeatSelector()),
                   ('mlAlgo',  SVC())
])

myGridSearch = GridSearchCV(myPipe, param_grid=myGrid, cv=LeaveOneOut())
myGridSearch.fit(X, y)
```

The "problem" is MyFeatSelector is refitted multiple times unnecessarily, which causes the whole thing to run too long. Can this be mitigated with mutiple grids or other sanctioned ways maybe?

I'm thinking about implementing somekind of memory within MyFeatSelector's fit_transform method, using the pandas index of y to know if a certain index combination with a certain k parameter was already fitted.

But I hope there are smarter ways to do this. I'm not interested in solutions like "use only 5 folds" etc. However any subsolutions like, how to force GridSearchCV to do the calculations in a certain order that makes reuse simpler are welcome! Thank you!